# Android Studio: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDex'

Tags: android, apache-poi, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm adding in a few libraries from Apache POI I had overcome several problems, but am now stuck on this error message when i'm trying to **run** the app;

```
> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBignerdranchAndroidExpandablerecyclerview103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubTraexExpandablelayoutLibrary13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 23.816 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Things I've tried:

- Using Enabling Multidex with javaMaxHeapSize
- Different versions of my required libraries
- Clean/Build 9000+ times
- Using the .java files (from apache site) and adding them to the dependencies
- Disabling proguard (for some reason)
- Going back and configuring JAVA_HOME + path
- Updating java (which ill try revert back to 1.7 tomorrow)
  and probably some other stuff.

Here is my build.gradle file without the error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.justin.wordcreator"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['Parse-*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.github.traex.expandablelayout:library:1.3'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-scratchpad:3.14'
    compile 'com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:1.03'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
    compile 'xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0'
}
```

If narrowed it down to these three libraries (Im using xmlbeans 2.3, but would like to get 2.6 working)

```
compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.14'
```

once i add any or all of them I get that error message.

Comment: Did you read the long error message starting with "Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*) when not building a core library"?

Answer (score 2):

There are some things that break when using bare POI on Android, e.g. the XMLBeans jar file has forbidden and duplicated classes which causes Android compilation to fail.

Take a look at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx which provides adjusted jar-files that seem to make using Apache POI on Android 5.x possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I ended up just downloading the Apache files and adding them all to the dependencies, I'm back to where i started ages ago, and that's this error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;"

Comment: Some of the jars contain "forbidden" classes from the javax.... package, Desktop-Javva does not care, but the Android-build fails, so you need something like https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx where this is fixed.

Comment: no luck, i checked out the libraries previously, they're directed at xlsx (excel). I've moved on to other libraries including docxj4 (android branch). I  was again close but had trouble using jaxb. I'll post a more detailed questions explaining what i've tried and where i should go next (on the verge of just editting an .xml copy of the template.doc with a base-64 class for images :/). Thanks though! if you know of any other libraries i could try out to simply create/load/edit/save word formats in android I'm all ears